# How to update a table with more than one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `refs` with citations (AU NAMES, which are separated by ; in one field authors) 
and a table called `aunames` with the AU-NAMES at each row. Now I would like to 
update my table `aunames` with the total number of authors for each citation.

```
 rec  ID  NAME  AUCOUNT
  1   3   AU1   
  2   3   AU2 
  ...
  ...
```

How can I do that? (auname_copy is a copy of auname.)
I tried:

```
 update aunames 
 set aucount = (select count(rec) 
                from refs 
                join aunames_copy on refs.id=aunames_copy.id  
                GROUP BY refs.id) ;
```

But I get the error:

> [Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

WHen I try only one row it works.

```
update aunames 
set aucount = (select count(rec) 
               from refs 
               join aunames_copy on refs.id=aunames_copy.id 
               where refs.id='1'  
               GROUP BY refs.id ) 
where id='1';
```

How can I loop through all rows?
Thanks

Comment: Why did you create `aunames_copy` ? Is it just because MySQL didn't allow updating the same table, since the same table was being referred in the query ?

Comment: Yes that was the reason.

Comment: Take GMB's first query and replace the copy table with original table. You don't need the copy; this technique is a workaround to MySQL's restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET` syntax:

```
UPDATE aunames a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.id, count(rec) cnt
    FROM refs r
    INNER JOIN aunames_copy c ON r.id = c.id  
    GROUP BY r.id
) x ON x.id = a.id
SET a.aucount = x.cnt
```

NB: if, as commented by [@MadhurBhaiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469308/madhur-bhaiya), you created table `aunames_copy` as a copy of original table `aunames`, your query can probably be simplified as:

```
UPDATE aunames a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, count(rec) cnt FROM refs GROUP BY id) x ON x.id = a.id
SET a.aucount = x.cnt
```

Comment: Your solution works, GMB, but the short form does not. THANKS a lot.